# inconsistency in converting string to integer, when string is hex, prefixed with '0x'

Tags: php, string-conversion

Using PHP 5.3.5. Not sure how this works on other versions.

I'm confused about using strings that hold numbers, e.g., `'0x4B0'` or `'1.2e3'`. The way how PHP works with such strings seems inconsistent to me. Is it only me? Or is it a bug? Or *undocumented feature*? Or am I just missing some magic sentence in docs?

```
<?php

echo $str = '0x4B0', PHP_EOL;
echo "is_numeric() -> ", var_dump(is_numeric($str)); // bool(true)
echo "*1           -> ", var_dump($str * 1);         // int(1200)
echo "(int)        -> ", var_dump((int)$str);        // int(0)
echo "(float)      -> ", var_dump((float)$str);      // float(0)
echo PHP_EOL;

echo $str = '1.2e3', PHP_EOL;
echo "is_numeric() -> ", var_dump(is_numeric($str)); // bool(true)
echo "*1           -> ", var_dump($str * 1);         // float(1200)
echo "(int)        -> ", var_dump((int)$str);        // int(1)
echo "(float)      -> ", var_dump((float)$str);      // float(1200)
echo PHP_EOL;
```

In both cases, `is_numeric()` returns `true`. Also, in both cases, `$str * 1` parses string and returns valid number (integer in one case, float in another case).

Casting with `(int)$str` and `(float)$str` gives unexpected results.

- `(int)$str` in any case is able to parse only digits, with optional "+" or "-" in front of them.
- `(float)$str` is more advanced and can parse something like `^[+-]?\d*(\.\d*)?(e[+-]?\d*)?`, i.e., optional "+" or "-", followed by optional digits, followed by optional decimal point with optional digits, followed by optional exponent which consists of "e" with optional "+" or "-" followed by optional digits. Fails on hex data though.

Related docs:

- [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/is_numeric) - states that "*Hexadecimal notation (0xFF) is allowed too but only without sign, decimal and exponential part*". If function, meant to test if a string holds numeric data, returns true, I expect PHP to be able to convert such string to a number. This seems to work with `$str * 1`, but not with casting. Why?
- [Converting to integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) - states that "*in most cases the cast is not needed, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires an integer argument*". After such statement, I expect both `$s * 10` and `(int)$s * 10` expressions to work the same way and to return the same result. Though, as shown in example, those expressions are evaluated differently.
- [String conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) - states that "*Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent*". "Exponent" is "e" or "E", followed by digits, e.g., `1.2e3` is valid numeric data. Sign ("+" or "-") is not mentioned. It does not mention hexidecimal values. This conflicts with definition of "numeric data" used in `is_numeric()`. Then, there is suggestion "*For more information on this conversion, see the Unix manual page for strtod(3)*", and `man strtod` describes additional numeric values (including HEX notation). So, after reading this, is hexidecimal data supposed to be valid or invalid numeric data?

So...

- Is there (or, rather, should there be) any relation between `is_numeric()` and the way how PHP treats strings when they are used as numbers?
- Why do `(int)$s`, `(float)$s` and `$s * 1` work differently, i.e,. give completely different results, when `$s` is `0x4B0` or `1.2e3`?
- Is there any way to convert a string to a number and keep its value, if it is written as `0x4B0` or as `1.2e3`? `floatval()` does not work with HEX at all, `intval()` needs `$base` to be set to `16` to work with HEX, typecasting with `(int)$str` and `(float)$str` sometimes works, sometimes does not work, so these are not valid options. I'm also not considering `$n *= 1;`, as it looks more like data manipulation rather than converting. Self-written functions also are not considered in this case, as I'm looking for *native solution*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct casts `(int)$str` and `(float)$str` don't really work differently at all: They both read as many characters from the string as they can interpret as a number of the respective type.

For "0x4B0", the int-conversion reads "0" (OK), then "x" and stops, because it cannot convert "x" into an integer. Likewise for the float-conversion.

For "1.2e3", the int-conversion reads "1" (OK), then "." and stops. The float-conversion recognises the entire string as valid float notation.

The automatic type recognition for an expression like `$str * 1` is simply more flexible than the explicit casts. The explicit casts require the integers and floats to be in the format produced by `%i` and `%f` in `printf`, essentially.

Perhaps you can use [intval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [floatval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) rather than explicit casts-to-int for more flexibility, though.

Finally, your question "is hexidecimal data supposed to be valid or invalid numeric data?" is awkward. There is no such thing as "hexadecimal data". Hexadecimal is just a number base. <s>What you *can* do is take a string like "4B0" and use `strtoul` etc. to parse it as an integer in *any* number base between 2 and 36.</s>[Sorry, that was BS. There's no `strtoul` in PHP. But `intval` has the equivalent functionality, see above.]

Comment: Did you mean `base_convert()`? Never heard of `strtoul()` :X

Comment: @KingCrunch: Yep, sorry, just realized that. Use `intval()` instead.

Comment: Oh, just realized, that `intval()` has a second parameter. I'm usually use `base_convert()` here, but that seems equivalent. Nice to know :)

Comment: @KingCrunch: Well, they're different things: `base_convert` goes from string to string, `intval` goes from string to number, if you believe in types. Both have their uses! :-)

Comment: `strtoul()` looks like `string to unsigned long`, which by definition cannot exist in PHP, as PHP does not have unsigned integers (from [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)).

Comment: @binaryLV: yes yes yes, I know, I already fixed that... :-( I was thinking about the nearest C function that came to mind and was put off guard by your mentioning of `strtod`. Sorry!

Comment: About using `intval()` - it requires `$base` to be specified to recognize hex. As for `(int)` not being able to recognize `x`, section that describes casting refers to "String conversion to numbers" section, which then refers to `man strtod(3)`, which mentions decimal numbers, hex numbers, infinity and NaN. After this "chain", I would expect PHP to be able to cast hexidecimal numbers to integers.

Comment: @binaryLV: Indeed, C's `strtoul` discovers base-16 and base-8 optionally from prefixed strings, <s>and so does `intval` according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php): `intval("0x1A")` gives 26</s> [scratch this, I was illiterate].

Comment: About question about "hexadecimal data" being awkward - I meant strings like "0x4B0", i.e., numbers in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: As for `intval("0x1A")` giving 26 - it gives me `int(0)`, if I do not manually set `$base` argument to 16. That example does not have quotes around number, i.e., it is `intval(0x1A)`, not `intval('0x1A')`.

Comment: @binaryLV: You're right, I misread the documentation! Sorry. Looks like `intval` isn't quite as powerful as `strtoul`. Oh well. Also, I knew what you "meant", it's just not what you said.

Comment: About `base_convert()` - it has serious problems with large numbers (I'm not sure how it handles small numbers). Try outputting `base_convert((1 << 31) | 1, 10, 2);` on 32bit system, it should consist of `1`, followed by 30 `0`, followed by another `1`. It is safer to use `decbin()`, `dechex()`, `hexdec()` etc. Though with both `baseconvert()` and these functions, base of input has to be known.

Comment: @binaryLV: Not sure about your example; I think `base_convert` should take a _string_ argument, so I'm not sure that `(1 << 32) | 1` even translates into the desired string. You will naturally have platform-specific limitations to the ranges of native data types...

Comment: `(1 << 32) | 1` is fully valid 32bit integer, 2147483649. It can be converted to string before passing to `base_convert()`, but it in no way changes result of `base_convert()`.

Comment: About mentioned 2147483649 - in PHP it is `-2147483647`.

Answer (score 2):

`intval` uses [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) which recognizes oct/hex prefixes when the `base` parameter is zero, so

```
var_dump(intval('0xef'));     // int(0)
var_dump(intval('0xff', 0));  // int(255)
```

Comment: Nice find. I didn't know that `$base` can be set to `0`. Seems to be an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there (or, rather, should there be) any relation between is_numeric() and the way how PHP treats strings when they are used as numbers?

There is no datatype called *numeric* in PHP, the `is_numeric()` function is more of a test for something that can be interpreted as number by PHP.

As far as such number interpreting is concerned, adding a `+` in front of the value will actually make PHP to convert it into a number:

```
$int = +'0x4B0';
$float = +'1.2e3';
```

You find this explained [in the manual for string, look for the section *String conversion to numbers*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

As it's triggered by an operator, I don't see any need why there should be a function in PHP that does the same. That would be superfluous.

---

Internally PHP uses a function called `zendi_convert_scalar_to_number` for the add operator (assumable `+`) that will make use of `is_numeric_string` to obtain the number.

The exact same function is called internally by `is_numeric()` when used with strings.

So to trigger the native conversion function, I would just use the `+` operator. This will ensure that you'll get back the numeric pseudo-type (int or float).

Ref: [/Zend/zend_operators.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_operators.c?revision=311346&view=markup); [/ext/standard/type.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/type.c?revision=306938&view=markup)

Comment: Nice try, though, `eval()` is even worse than `$n += 0;` or `$n *= 1;`.

Comment: Yes it is, I would prefer your expression instead. Stricly, eval would require a `is_numeric()` upfront which returns true on that string.

Comment: Found another native one. Looks like prefixing with a simple `+` is working as well.

Comment: @binaryLV, I was skimming through source, and it looks like that the `is_numeric()` shares it's commons with `+` on strings regarding the conversion.

Comment: Nice find (about the source).