# Problems determing if value is a number

Tags: php

I am doing this check on a variable:

```
if (empty($num) || !isset ($num) || !is_numeric ($num))
{
    $population = -1;
}
else
{
    $population = $num;
}
```

And what I was hoping for is that if num is null or not a number or doesn't exist, to make $population = -1 and in all other cases to give $population the value of $num

But that is not happening for me.  Any ideas why this isn't working the way I thought it would?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly is the problem? just if (!is_numeric ($num)) alone should do the trick.

Comment: Be careful: `0` is considered empty, too.

Comment: Is population a positive integer number always?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6438864/367456

Comment: The code seems to work for me.  I tried $num = "", $num = "a", and removing $num completely, and they all set $population to -1.  When I tried $num=4 and $num="4", and they set $population to 4.  What was the case where this was failing for you?

Comment: @ryan I am suspecing empty or null values being a problem

Comment: When doesn't the code do what you want?

Comment: @GeekedOut I tried setting $num=NULL and $population was set to -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this possibly an issue with scoping?

```
<?php
$num=23;
tryStuff();

function tryStuff(){

    global $num; //if this line is commented out, then -1 is printed. 
    if (empty($num) || !isset ($num) || !is_numeric ($num))
    {
        $population = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        $population = $num;
    }
    echo "$population<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

post an example of `$num`

using regex:

```
$population  = preg_match("/^\d+$/", $num) ? $num : -1;
```

Comment: Why use a regular expression if you don't *need* to?

Comment: $num shouldn't matter.  Thats the point of my question.  And not sure I need regex here.  Just proper checking for nulls, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) should work good by itself. If instead of `$num` the value was a super global, using [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) would be a good idea to avoid warnings:

```
$population = is_numeric ($num) ? $num : -1;
// or
$population = isset($_GET['num']) && is_numeric($_GET['num']) ? $num : -1;
```

Comment: That didn't quite work.  I think it just does the same thing I posted above, but in a more compact way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that you're inputting the number `0` and getting unexpected results, because `empty(0)` is `true`.

I think if you change your code to:

```
if (!isset ($num) || !is_numeric ($num))
{
    $population = -1;
}
else
{
    $population = $num;
}
```

You will get the desired results.

**EDIT** Possibly you are looking for an Integer or a Float in which case you should replace `is_numeric` with [`is_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) or [`is_float`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Why not flip it around and go with a positive as a primary check?

```
$population = (isset($num) && is_numeric($num)) ? $num : -1;
```

I've never had fun with negative's and "or" statements :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you `var_dump($num);`?

Personally, my guess is that PHP is interpreting something input as a number, when you are expecting it to be a string. Such examples might include things which might accidentally convert, like `'0xFF'` (a string of the Hex for 255).

Clearly the issue is not about `isset`, because if it were, you would have caught it, and you said to evolve that this happens even without empty. This means that something which you are expecting to be `is_numeric($num) === FALSE` can be evaluated as `TRUE`.