# PHP Pack function doesn't like string

Tags: php, pack

Needing some help with the pack() function in PHP. The docs are over my head..

I have the following code:

```
$arr_upc = array();
    if ($user_pass_code !== '' )
    {
        $arr_upc = str_split($user_pass_code); // Split provided pass code into char array for building the command
    }else{
        $arr_upc = str_split('0000'); // Provide an invalid code by default
    }

    //$arr_upc[0], $arr_upc[1], $arr_upc[2], $arr_upc[3]
    $num1 = '0x0' . $arr_upc[0];
    $num2 = '0x0' . $arr_upc[1];
    $num3 = '0x0' . $arr_upc[2];
    $num4 = '0x0' . $arr_upc[3];

    $cmd = pack("C*", 0x78, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x53);

    //$cmd = pack("C*", 0x78, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, 0x0E, 0x53); // WHAT I'D LIKE TO USE BUT NOT WORKING
```

When I use it like this:
$cmd = pack("C*", 0x78, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x53);

It works fine.

When I attempt to replace some of the items in that list with a string variable, it fails:
$cmd = pack("C*", 0x78, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4, 0x0E, 0x53); // Fails

I'm guessing pack doesn't like it or that I need to convert that to something before inputting it into the function, but I'm lost now.

Comment: Your issue isn't the `pack` function. Constructing a string `"0x09"` will not make PHP interpret it as numeric `0x09` literal. -- What's all this supposed to do anyway?

Comment: Cast string into number, for example like this - `pack("C*", 0x78, 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, $num1 * 1, $num2 * 1, $num3 * 1, $num4 * 1, 0x0E, 0x53)` Also, look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438864/inconsistency-in-converting-string-to-integer-when-string-is-hex-prefixed-with

Comment: Thanks Cheery, I will try that. That makes sense mario. I kind of "knew" that it wouldn't be equal in a literal sense, but wasn't sure what that missing step was to convert it to a number. This is part of a web app that will interface with a Bosch alarm panel (I'm coding the arm/disarm functionality using their API).

Answer (score 1):

try this change:

```
$num1 =  0+'0x'.$arr_upc[0];
$num2 =  0+'0x'.$arr_upc[1];
$num3 =  0+'0x'.$arr_upc[2];
$num4 =  0+'0x'.$arr_upc[3];
```